# error pagination in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

My pagination is work fine, but it's show error when wanting to raise data over existing data
For example, `show/index/5` or `show/index/10` works fine and the data is right. But if I go to `show/index/120` it shows error

```
   Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

**Here's my controller**

```
   public function index(){
       $config['base_url']=base_url()."book/show/index"; 
       $config['total_rows']= $this->book_model->get_book(); 
       $config['per_page']=5; 
       $config['num_links'] = 5; 
       $config['uri_segment']=4; 
       $config['full_tag_open'] = "<ul class='pagination'>";
       $config['full_tag_close'] ="</ul>";
       $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
       $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
       $config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li class='disabled'><li class='active'><a href='#'>";

       $config['first_link']='< Pertama '; 
       $config['last_link']='Terakhir > '; 
       $config['next_link']='> '; 
       $config['prev_link']='< '; 
       $this->pagination->initialize($config);

       $this->load->model('admin/book_model');
       $data['book']=$this->book_model->count_book($config);
       $this->load->view('admin/book', $data);
  }
```

Comment: you could probably check the number of pages against the given uri argument

Comment: how do i check it ??

Comment: just use an if statement, if the argument provided is less than or equal to the total books divided by books per page, else, argument is not valid

Comment: im sorry, where i put the statement ?? im newbiee

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/pagination-with-codeigniter/

Comment: @wolfgang1983 i've try but not solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view you have to apply a check in your code

```
if(!empty($result)&& isset($result)){                          
     foreach($results as $data){
                    ----your code--
                     }
```